# request.session.modified vs SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST

Tags: django, django-sessions

I understand how these work differently in practice. For example, if I have:

```
request.session.['cart'].remove('item')
```

the session won't be saved without explicitly calling `request.session.modified = True`

or having `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True` in settings.py.

Or I could get around using either by using:

```
cart = request.session['cart']
cart.remove('item')
request.session['cart'] = cart
```

My question is if there is any drawback to using SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST whether in performance or unintended consequences. I don't see any reason why I wouldn't want to save the session if I modified a value in it.

Comment: Sessions are stored at the server side. This can be done in a (memory)cache, filesystem, or the database. Especially for the last two, each time saving it would result in overhead to the filesystem/database, since it is not guaranteed that anything has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (…) if there is any drawback to using `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` whether in performance or unintended consequences. I don't see any reason why I wouldn't want to save the session **if I modified a value in it**.

Well `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` will save the session *each* time. Regardless whether you made hanges, since Django can not (perfectly) detect that. This thus means that at the end of every request, the session will be serialized.

Sessions are stored at the *server* side. It will set a cookie in the client's browser with the session key, but the data of the session itself is stored at the server side. There are several ways to store sessions, this can be done in e (memory) cache, but also in a file on the filesystem, or in a database. Especially the last two will generate some overhead in terms of filesystem I/O, or database queries. While these operations will likely not be the bottleneck, it is an extra source of queries or disk I/O, and thus will have some implications on performance and probably the price of hosting the application.

Comment: Can you think of a more "pythonic way" to accomplish the example, such as a one liner?  Besides: request.session['cart'] = request.session.['cart'].remove('item')